# What is an easy way to assign member variables of base class templates

Tags: templates, visual-c++, derived-class

I have a class called interface that takes a file provided by user input and then depending on that file type it will initialize a member variable of type BaseDefinitions that is used to map out the specific bytes of the file.

**Base**

```
template<class T, class U>
class BaseDefinition 
{
public:

    T getHeaderBlock()  { T new_header_block = {};  return new_header_block; };
    U getDataBlock()    { U new_data_block = {}; return new_data_block; };

    virtual bool        validateBytes(T& definition) = 0;  
    virtual float       getDataPoint(U& data) = 0;
};
```

**Derived**

```
struct  FileAHeaderBlock {
    ...
};

struct FileADataBlock {
    ...
};

class FileADefinition : public BaseDefinition<FileAHeaderBlock, FileADataBlock >
{
public:
     bool       validateBytes(FileAHeaderBlock& definition) override;
     float      getDataPoint(FileADataBlock & data) override;
}
```

**Interface header file**

```
class FileInterface
{
public:
    FileInterface();
    ~FileInterface();
    void loadDefinition(std::string &file_type);

private:
    void extract_header();
    BaseDefinition* definition_; //Here is the member variable I am trying to set
    std::vector<int> values_;
```

};

**Interface.cpp**

```
void FileInterface::load_defintion(const std::string& filepath)
{
    //Psuedo code
    if (file_type == std::string(".fileA"))
        definition_ = FileADefinition;
    else if (file_type == std::string(".fileB"))
        definition = FileBDefinition;
}

void FileInterface::extract_header()
{   
    auto header_buffer = definition_.getHeaderBlock();

    //read bits into header buffer
    
    if (!file_.read((char*)(&header_buffer), sizeof(header_buffer)))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("File could not be read: ");
    }

    if (!definition_.validateBytes(header_buffer))
    {
        std::cout << "got: " << std::string(std::begin(header_buffer.MAGIC), std::end(header_buffer.MAGIC)) << std::endl;
    }
    
    values_ = header_buffer.DATA;
}
```

When I try to build this I get a compiler error from Visual studio saying that the argument list for class template BaseDefinition is missing.

I thought I could set the member variable to a base class then cast to a derived class when I know what file the user wants.

The classes FileADefinition and FileBDefinition both have the same functions just different implementation so I would really like to take advantage of the Object Oriented nature. It seems the structure I use to initialize them is the sticking point. What am I missing that could be done here?

Comment: I do not know what types I will need until run time as I explained above since there is user input in what file gets selected. So I cant just set it in the member class.

Comment: Every type must be known at compile time in C++, just as you can't define a number variable and decide at runtime whether it's an int or a float. You could redesign it so that all `BaseDefinition<T, U>` derive from a common class `BaseBaseDefinition` for example, and store a pointer to `BaseBaseDefinition` instead, but that's a different question.

Comment: Wouldnt that defeat the purpose of the base class? I added more context in the post about why I structured it the way I did. It seems that there is something seriously wrong with my code, what question can I ask so that the title is more appropriate.

Comment: The functions you listed all depend on the specific types `T, U`, and they would all be (very) different for different types, so there is nothing to "abstract" about that. Presumably, you have other higher-level functions which would be independent of the types, and can be shared between the different types, which you want to put in a common base. But that's hard to guess without more context.

Comment: The intent was to have FileInterface handle the higher level functions. It has a file it loads using fstream, and a user defined class of the nature FileADefinition, FileBDefinition derived from BaseDefinition, that tells where to find the bytes it needs. So under the hood the file interface doesnt care what file it is, since the processing is the same. i.e load a file definition , grab the header, parse the header to then grab the data, parse the data. I thought my code was decent until I ran into this.

Comment: Imagine you somehow managed to declare `definition_` the way you want. How will `FileInterface` use it? How will it know what it's supposed to pass to, say, `validateBytes`? Show an example of the intended usage. Say, what is "grab the header" supposed to look like, in code?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I added some psuedo code that for what you asked.

Comment: Just make `extract_header` a virtual method on `BaseDefinition`, drop the other four. `extract_header` doesn't depend on `T` and `U`, so `BaseDefinition` won't need to be a template. Have `BaseDefinition::extract_header` take a stream as a parameter, and return `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: C++ types don't work the way you want, you will need to restructure your code. One way of doing that would be not to expose the result of `getHeaderBlock` outside of `Definition` classes. Its type is not actually needed in `extract_header`, that function only operates with bytes, so `getHeaderBlock` could expose bytes. Or perhaps `extract_header` should be implemented in `BaseDefinition` and `FileInterface` would just call that implementation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I do not think that will work since to get the stream I need to read from the file I need to load header or data block from the definition. I think I will try to split the encoding/decoding of the data and file structure generator features from the Definition classes into two separate classes. Are there any creational or design patterns that you can recommend for this?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.I think this is the best answer although Im a little lost how to go about it. Would you mind giving a bit of code to explain your answer and ill happily accept it and close this.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines, perhaps. This should be functionally equivalent to your current example.

```
class BaseDefinition {
public:
  virtual std::vector<int> extract_header(std::istream& input) = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
class BaseDefinitionImpl : public BaseDefinition {
protected:
  virtual bool        validateBytes(T& definition) = 0;  
public:
  std::vector<int> extract_header(std::istream& input) override {
    T header_buffer;
    if (!file_.read((char*)(&header_buffer), sizeof(header_buffer)))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("File could not be read: ");
    }
    if (!validateBytes(header_buffer)) {
      std::cout << "Bad things happened";
    }
    return header_buffer.DATA;
  }
};

class FileADefinition : public BaseDefinitionImpl<FileAHeaderBlock, FileADataBlock >
{
public:
     bool validateBytes(FileAHeaderBlock& definition) override;
}

class FileInterface {
public:
    void loadDefinition(std::string &file_type) {
      if (file_type == std::string(".fileA"))
        definition_ = std::make_unique<FileADefinition>();
    }

private:
    void extract_header() {
      values_ = definition_->extract_header(file_);
    }
    std::unique_ptr<BaseDefinition> definition_;
    std::vector<int> values_;
};
```

Comment: My rep is actually too low to accept but I just wanted to thank you for responding.